# How to typecast class a to class b in c++

Tags: c++, casting

Why ostringstream to ostream type casting working but vice versa not Working ?

```
int main()
{
   //part #1
   ostringstream   oss;
   ostream& os=oss ; 
   // ^^ It  works 
   
   //part #2
   ostream os2 ; 
   ostringstream& oss2=os2; 
    cout <<"address is "<<&oss; 
   // ^^ It doesn't  work 
    


     
    return 0;
}
```

Part #2 of code throws an error 
" error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is protected within this context" . 
How can I fix this issue ?

**Edit :-**
Take a look at this code , I want to access response in curlCall function without making anychange in any function's params

```
size_t CurlDataWrite(void* buf,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void* userp)
{
    
//code to write stream    
    ostream& os=*static_cast<ostream*>(userp);
    streamsize len=size*nmemb ; 
    if(os.write(static_cast<char*> (buf),len))
        return len ; 
        
        
        return 0 ;
}

void curlCall(ostream& os) 
{
 
   

  CURL* curl=curl_easy_init();  
 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,&CurlDataWrite)  ; 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURL_FILE,&os); 
 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, "https://something.com"); 
 int code=curl_easy_perform(curl) ; 
 //how to get curl response here instead of in main function ???? 
}
int main()
{ 
    ostringstream oss;
    curlCall(oss);

    //i can get response here by calling the following code 
    cout << oss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `ostream` is a base class for `ostringstream`

Comment: Use Part #1?...

Comment: @Jarod42 , But the problem is , I am working on some bug fixation .  so , basically the existing code is we are sending 
ostringstream object to a function which performs curl operations the curl function parameter which is taking ostringstream object is of type ostream . because of this I am not able to process the response of curl because ostringstream function doesn't work in the curl function

Comment: Maybe provide that relevant code (or even better simplified version)?

Comment: @Jarod42,  Take a look at edited post

Comment: `void curlCall(ostream& os)`, it seems you want `void curlCall(ostringstream& os)` instead.

Comment: conversions are not symmetric. You can make a table from a tree but the other way around isnt that easy

Comment: Should `curlCall(std::cout)` be valid?

Answer (score 1):

> how to get curl response here instead of in main function ????

`void curlCall(ostream& os)` is not designed for doing this. So you can do one of the following:

- change `curlCall` interface so that it can do this (which means changing `ostream` parameter type to `ostringstream`)
- don't do this in `curlCall`

If you want to do this in `curlCall` without changing `curlCall` interface, then you have  self-contradictory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your response to Jarod42's answer this seems to be more of a refactoring problem. Your problem is that you go from ostream -> ostringstream -> ostream, a possible solution is that you should just keep the function general and take in an ostream instead or separate the two functions.

Comment: Take a look at updated code